# How do revalidation intervals work with NextJS?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Say I have the following code:

```js
//Some Component that takes props
export async function getStaticProps(){
  //fetch some meetups data from an API

  return {
    props: { 
      meetups: fetchedMeetups
    },
    revalidate: 10
 };
}
```

Any request within the first 10 seconds will cause the page the re-generate the static HTML file using the latest fetched data. Any subsequent request after that first request but before the end of the time interval will receive this newly generated page. My question is: is this interval constant from the time the page is first served? Is there some interval timer running after the first request that is continually being reset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there some interval timer running after the first request that is continually being reset?

No – there doesn't need to be a running timer at all.

Instead, you (or Next.js) save the time when you last fetched the data; when a request comes in, and it's been over `revalidate` seconds since that last time (or if it has never happened), fetching re-occurs, and the new time is saved.